# adobe-dc-view dynamic URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, adobe, adobe-embed-api

I want to get the file from the code behind in c# with adobe dc view ,
and i don't know how to do it , and i don't find examples on internet.

If anyone can help , here is The code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">  
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Document</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div id="adobe-dc-view"></div>
<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function () {
        var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({ clientId: "xxxxxxxxxx", divId: "adobe-dc-view" });
        adobeDCView.previewFile({
            content: { location: { url: "myfile.pdf" } },
            metaData: { fileName: "myfile.pdf" }
        }, {
showAnnotationTools: false, showLeftHandPanel: false, showDownloadPDF: false,showPrintPDF: false });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using content.location.url, pass the content as a Promise that resolves to a ByteArray. Have your C# application return a Blob to the HTML page and then load that into Embed API (view-sdk) via the Promise.

```
adobeDCView.previewFile(
      {
        content: { promise: Promise.resolve(blob.arrayBuffer()) },
        metaData: { fileName: url.split("/").slice(-1)[0] }
      },
```

The full code is at [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/practicalPDF/pen/qBbbdvE)